# What differences are there between a Privately Published post and a Draft post?

Tags: posts, publish, post-status, private, draft

WordPress has three different post statuses:

- Published
- Pending Review
- Draft

It also has three different visibility options:

- Public
- Password protected
- Private

When you set a post to Published and Private, WordPress will display its status as **Privately Published**.

Are there any differences between a post status of **Draft** vs. **Privately Published?** They seem to behave very similarly.

Comment: published has a pretty permalink url while draft won't get one

Comment: @Vishwa - Good point. Would you mind adding that as an answer?

Comment: [Post status](https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-status/)

Answer (score 3):

It may be a little bit confusing, but there are significant differences:

- Publish - published post that anyone can see
- Future - post scheduled to be published
- Draft - incomplete post viewable by anyone with proper user role; it doesn't have it's permalink assigned yet, so you can view it only as a preview
- Pending - post awaiting a user with the `publish_posts` capability to publish
- Private - viewable only to WordPress users at Administrator level - the permalink is assigned.

Comment: Editors also have the ability to edit other peoples' Private posts. Authors, on the other hand, can only edit their own Private posts.

Comment: @Pikamander2 it doesn’t matter if the post is private or not - author always can edit only his posts and editor always can edit all posts.

Answer (score 0):

Draft posts (and Pending Review posts) *do* have permalinks a.k.a. URLs. The URL is automatically generated the first time you save the post as a Draft or Pending Review. Considering that, I can't tell any real difference between Draft/Pending and Privately Published posts/pages, other than the folders in which they're saved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party ;), but I just found out that in my theme, there is a difference between a draft and a private post. A draft can be seen in the searchresults when you would search for the post title. When clicking on it, it shows a 404 page. By setting it to private, the draft doesn't show up in the searchresults.

I don't know if this is a wordpress thing, or just my theme. Personally I find it a bit stupid. To me a draft should always be private. That's what a draft is, right?

So, it might be different per theme, but it is possible that both options have a different outcome :).